# Meteor: Accessing group function of mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mapreduce

I'm trying to get an average of a data collection of unknown size, so I'd like like to write something like this on the server side:

```
@Mileage = new Meteor.Collection("mileage")

Meteor.publish "average",  ->
  Mileage.group
    initial:
      count: 0
      total: 0

    reduce: (doc, out) ->
      out.count++
      out.total += doc.mileage

    finalize: (out) ->
      out.avg = out.total / out.count
```

I can do a `meteor mongo` and this code (translated into Javascript, of course) works fine. How do I access the aggregate functions like `Collection.group`? Or is there a better way to do this that I'm missing?

Also, is something like this reactive. Assume I have something on the client that subscribes to this and it is referenced in a template. When something in the `mileage` document collection changes, the average will change. Will I be able to rely on Meteor's reactive updating to push this out to the clients?

Answer (score 2):

Meteor doesn't support aggregation directly. To use these other features you need to do it manually.

You could use the [mongodb-aggregation](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/mongodb-aggregation) plugin on atmosphere to do most of the missing stuff.

The only thing is that you can't do these types of queries properly on the client (minimongo). You can do them but the query will be relayed to the server with a method call. (Meaning its not reactive)

You could reproduce your group query with an aggregation pipeline or a map reduce query.

If you want to get some kind of reactive like query on the client you could interpret the data in your handlebars helpers, [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) might be helpful:

```
Template.hello.average = function() {
    var count;
    var data = YourCollection.find().map(function(doc) {
        count++;
        return doc.mileage;
    });


    var reduce = _.reduce(data, function(total, item) {
        return total+item;
    });

    return reduce / count;

}
```

Of course it could do with a bit of modification to what you want to do, but the idea is to use underscore's reduce in place of minimongo's lack of it.

Comment: I am obviously not getting a couple of things here. If I have a data collection of (say) 20K documents, computing averages on the client is probably a bad idea. Wouldn't that make the parallelism between client and server irrelevant? I'm also not sure how to make it so when someone changes their mileage everyone sees the average change.

Comment: Maybe you could store a cached value of it in another collection and calculate it on the server. This way you could have it both be reactive & not worry too much about the size of the computation?